# Return unique values from one array into two different variables?

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, while-loop, unique

I'm trying to ensure that the "thing2" value is never equal to the "thing1", from values pulled from the same array. This is what I have come up with:

```
const array = ["item1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]

//randomiser
const random = array => {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()* array.length)];
}

//function for selecting array value unique for each "thing"
const goal = () => {
  let thing1 = random(array)

  const diffRand = () => {
    while (thing1 !== this.thing2) {
    return random(array);
    }

  let thing2 = diffRand();
  }
}
```

1. How do I prevent the value from array in `thing1` being also called into `thing2`? Currently the process is completely random and will sometimes pull in the same value - obviously I'm missing an essential step here to prevent replication.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```js
const array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];

const random = (array) => {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() *  array.length)];
}

const goal = () => {
    let thing1 = random(array);
    let thing2;
    do {
        thing2 = random(array);
    } while (thing1 === thing2);
    console.log(`${thing1}, ${thing2}`);
}
for (let _ of Array(5)) {
  goal();
}
```